# Receive online (offline) JMeter measurements (Throughput, HIT's per second, Transactions) in non-UI mode, with/without JMeter plugin

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

The goal is to receive online measurements while running a JMX test (in non-UI mode).
Is an existing/new plugin needed (modify existing plugin to be able to save and send the data to my dashboard)?
Any examples/tutorial?

Comment: Please share more details? About your environment, JMeter setup. What you have already tried. What results you are getting already?

Comment: I'm running the JMX test from my own Java code (jmeter.run();) I have tried to modify the JMeterUtils.setProperty("summariser") -> and can get offline results. I am now trying to get online measurements (Throughput / HIT's per second) and errors. The goal is not to change original JMeter source. What do you suggest? Is a new/exiting plugin needed? Maybe familiar with an existing example / documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this documentation:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html

You can use an InfluxDB backend to receive the live results and use Grafana to display the graphs from InfluxDB

Comment: Can you please specify? If I understand correct, I should:

1) Open .jmx in JMeter UI -> Add -> Listener -> Backend Listener (can this be done without UI - API/other way that you suggest?)
2) To be able to receive the live results and send them to my own DB (for example, send data point to my http server) - I need to:
Implement: public class MyNewBackendListenerClient extends AbstractBackendListenerClient implements Runnable { ?

- Is there maybe a similar example for this?
- My goal is not to change original JMeter binaries. After implementing, how should I add the new .class?
Thanks